# objReminder.Start = Range("h" & i) not working

Tags: vba, excel

I have this code:

```
Sub StoreReminders()
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim i As Integer
    LastRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    i = 2
    Debug.Print LastRow
    Dim appOL As Object
     Dim objReminder As Object

    Set appOL = GetObject(, "Outlook.application")
     Set objReminder = appOL.CreateItem(1) ' olAppointmentItem
     For i = 2 To LastRow
     Debug.Print i
     Debug.Print Range("h" & i)
     objReminder.Start = Range("h" & i)
     objReminder.Duration = Range("I" & i)
     objReminder.Subject = "Renew " & Range("a" & i)
     objReminder.ReminderSet = True
     objReminder.Save
     Next i
End Sub
```

It breaks at `objReminder.Start = Range("h" & i)` because according to the `Debug.Print` code, it is returning the entire column of dates instead of just the date in H2

Does the `Range("a" & i)` code not work in conjunction with `objReminder.Start`?
`Debug.print` prints it out correctly.

Comment: debug.print can only print one string. it cannot print arrays. please check H2. it may contain invalid data

Comment: don't forget that the code loops, so debug.print repeats a bunch of times

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you check the MSDN entry for the [`Start`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa212409(v=office.11).aspx) property then it says:

> Returns or sets a **Date** indicating the starting date and time for the appointment or **Journal** entry. Read/write.

(their emphasis)

So, in your VBA code, I would change this line:

```
objReminder.Start = Range("h" & i)
```

To this:

```
objReminder.Start = CDate(Range("h" & i).Value)
```

Using the `CDate` function which converts a value to a date.